# Functional Analysis- invertible operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let ${c_n}$ $\in \ell^{\infty}$, and let $T_{c_n}$$\in$ B$(\ell^2)$, $\:$ be defined by $\\$

$T_{c_n}$ ({$x_n$}) = {$c_nx_n$}. $\\$

1. If inf {$\vert c_n \vert$: n $\in\mathbb{N}$} $\gt$ 0 , and $d_n$ = $\cfrac{1}{c_n}$ , $\\$

Show that $d_n$ $\in$ $\ell^{\infty}$, $\;$  and that $\:$ $T_{c_n}$$T_{d_n}$ = $T_{d_n}$$T_{c_n}$= I .$\\$

2. If ${c_n}$ = $\cfrac{1}{n}$ ,$\:$ Show that $T_{c_n}$ is not invertible. $\\$

Please any hint or solution to this problem will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What ideas have you considered?  What barriers did you run into?

Comment: E.g., why is the condition
$$
\inf \{ |c_{n}| \; : \; n \in \mathbb{N} \} > 0
$$
needed?

Comment: @avs I think it is to avoid a situation where we have to divide by zero. Such that $d_n$ = $\cfrac{1}{c_n}$ , $\\$ returns a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: That's a good start.  However, if we take $c_{n} = 1/n$ (as in the counterexample you are given), none of the $c_{n}$'s is zero, so we never divide by zero.  Still, there is an issue with the $d_{n}$'s.  What is that issue?

Comment: @avs Please, can you point it out to me?. I can't see any issue with the $d_{n}$'s. Thanks.

Comment: ${\cal l}^\infty$ is the space of all *bounded* sequences.  The sequence
$$
d_{n} = {1 \over c_{n}} = n
$$
is not bounded, hence is not in ${\cal l}^\infty$.

Comment: @avs If you conclude that d_{n} is not in {\cal l}^\infty. Then how would you show that   $\:$ $T_{c_n}$$T_{d_n}$ = $T_{d_n}$$T_{c_n}$= I .$\\$. That would result into a contradiction.

Comment: The result $T_{d_{n}} T_{c_{n}} = I$ would be valid only if $d_{n}$ is in ${\cal l}^{\infty}$, and that's what we are asked to prove.  The condition 
$$
\inf \{ c_n  \; : n  \in \mathbb{N} \} > 0
$$
is needed precisely because it implies that $\{d_{n}\} \in {\cal l}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that $\{c_{n}\} \in {\cal l}^{\infty}$ and that so is
$$
\left\{d_{n} = {1 \over c_{n} } \; : \; n = 1, 2, \ldots \right\},
$$
let's experiment: take any sequence $x = \{x_{n}\} \in {\cal l}^{2}$, which I will write in the form
$$
x = \left(x_1, \; x_2, \; x_3, \ldots \right).
$$

Applying $T_{c}$ to $x$, we get:
$$
T_{c} x = \left(c_1 x_1, \; c_2 x_2, \; c_3 x_3, \ldots \right)
$$
Since $c \in {\cal l}^{\infty}$ (i.e., is a bounded sequence), it follows that $T_{c} x$ is in ${\cal l}^{2}$.  To see this, let $C = \sup_{n} |c_{n}|$, and estimate: for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
|c_{n} x_{n}| \leq C|x_{n}|
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} c_{n}^2 \; x_{n}^{2} \leq C^2 \; \sum_{n \geq 0} x_{n}^{2} < \infty.
$$

Now, let's apply $T_{d}$ to $T_{c}x$:
$$
T_{d} \left( T_{c} x \right) = \left(d_1 c_1 x_1, \; d_2 c_2 x_2, \; d_3 c_3 x_3, \ldots \right) = 
\left( {1 \over c_{1}} c_1 x_1, \; {1 \over c_2} c_2 x_2, \; {1 \over c_3} c_3 x_3, \ldots \right) = ??
$$

Comment: $T_{d} \left( T_{c} x \right)$ = $ \left(x_1, \; x_2, \; x_3, \ldots \right).$ = I. Hope I am right. Thanks alot.

Comment: @VincentEbuka, yes!  Now try $T_c (T_d x)$.  Also, did the explanation about a sequence being bounded make sense?

Comment: Yes the explanation was helpful. Thanks very much.

Comment: In part (2) of the problem. Is it sufficient to say that  $T_{c_n}$ is not invertible because  $c_{n}'s \neq 0$

Comment: No.  In part (2), the problem arises with the $d$'s.

Comment: See my last comment under your question.

Comment: Yes I have been trying to figure out the meaning all day. But I find it contradicting...As in, in your second comment under the question you concluded that $d_n \notin {\cal l}^{\infty}$. Then in your last comment under the question, we have again that the The result $T_dnT_cn=I$ would be valid only if $d_n$ is in ${\cal l}^{\infty}$, and that's what we are asked to prove. The condition
inf{$c_n$:n∈N}>0
is needed precisely because it implies that ${d_n}∈{\cal l}^{\infty}$. Those two statements are confusing to me. I would appreciate more clarification. Thanks

Comment: Here is how your problem reads to me.  Part 1. asks to prove that  if $c = \{c_{n}\}_{n \neq 0}$ satisfies
$$\inf \{ c_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} > 0,$$
then the operator $T_c$ is invertible, and its inverse is $T_{d}$, where $d = \{d_n = 1/c_{n}\}_{n \geq 0}$.

Part 2. gives a $c$ that fails the condition with the inf and produces an operator $T_{c}$ that is not invertible.

What's the contradiction?